# asp boilerplate implement IEntityHistoryStore Not Working

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I use asp boilerplate framework and I implemented IEntityHistoryStore as you can see , I make break point on EntityHistoryService Constructor ... but when i run project ; My project will not be stopped at breakPoint ; As if it never goes to service implementation ; Or when i call any SaveChange my SaveAsync override is not called

```
public class EntityHistoryService : IEntityHistoryStore
{
    private IRepository<NoeEntityChangeSet, long> _repository { get; set; }
    private IObjectMapper _objectMapper { get; set; }

    public EntityHistoryService(IRepository<NoeEntityChangeSet, long> repository, IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    void IEntityHistoryStore.Save(EntityChangeSet entityChangeSet)
    {
         My Custom implement
    }

    Task IEntityHistoryStore.SaveAsync(EntityChangeSet entityChangeSet)
    {
        My Custom implement
    }
}
```

In ApplicationModule

```
 Configuration.ReplaceService<IEntityHistoryStore, EntityHistoryService>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

In CoreModule

```
 Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;
 Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(new NamedTypeSelector("Abp.Auditable", type => typeof(IFullAudited).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
```

Comment: In which method did you call `ReplaceService`?

Comment: In PreInitialize

Comment: public class BaseApplicationModule : AbpModule
      {
              ...other code

              public override void PreInitialize()
              {
            
                    Configuration.ReplaceService<IEntityHistoryStore, 
               EntityHistoryService>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
                }

                     ...other code
           }

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).